# Prevent yarn from deleting files under vendor

Tags: linux, windows, docker, yarnpkg

I'm developing on a Windows machine with a Linux docker image. I'm using `node-sass` which has native bindings stored under `node_modules/node-sass/vendor`

Every time I add or update a package using yarn, I have to enter the docker image and manually re-run `npm rebuild node-sass` in order to reinstate the linux-x64 binding.

Is there a way to tell yarn to not delete files in this folder?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem like `node_modules` is portable across operating systems. The way I've always been working around this is to not share `node_modules` between Linux and Windows, i.e. when running via Docker, mount a volume on `node_modules` by specifying a path on the Linux host or using a Docker volume. This way, you get two sets of `node_modules`, one under Linux, the other under Windows.

Comment: The trouble I run into is I can't run `yarn` from within my docker container because I'm requiring a git repo and the volume that is cross-mounted to my Windows environment is a git submodule... I just get the error `fatal: Not a git repository: ../.git/modules/<mydir>`

Comment: Ah, I also used another trick for that :D You can mount `/dev/null` as `.git` in the repo, since `.git` is just a regular file in the case of sub-modules. Kinda hacky, but works.

Comment: that sounds like it might work - how do I mount /dev/null from a docker-compose file? I tried `- /dev/null:/app/.git/` but that says "Not a valid Windows path"